# How do I avoid UnsatisfiedLinkError when calling C++ from java from C++ application?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm embedding Java into a C++ application. As part of this I need to expose native functions to java, as well as calling java functions from C++.

Do I need to put the functions I want to call from java into a shared library? Or can they be compiled into the host application somehow?

Here's what I've tried so far, but it gives a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

*Compilation*

I'm building on OS X 10.5 using

```
g++ -Wall -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers/ -framework JavaVM -g test.cpp
```

*Java Test File :  TestObject.java*

```
// To build this you need to do a `javac TestObject.java`
// To get the signatures do a `javap -d TestObject`
// To generate the .h file do a `javah TestObject`
public class TestObject
{
    public native TestObject get_property( String k ); 
}
```

*C++ Test File : test.cpp*

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <assert.h>


JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_TestObject_get_1property(JNIEnv * jni_env, jobject obj, jstring key)
{
  //Just a stub implementation for now.
  jclass klass = jni_env->GetObjectClass( obj );
  jmethodID constructor = jni_env->GetMethodID( klass, "<init>", "()V");
  jobject retval = jni_env->NewObject(klass, constructor );

  return retval;
}




int main()
{
  JavaVM* jvm;
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
  JavaVMOption options[1];

  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

  JNIEnv * env;
  JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);

  jclass klass = (env)->FindClass("TestObject");
  assert( klass );

  jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID( klass, "<init>", "()V");
  assert( constructor );

  jobject obj = env->NewObject(klass, constructor );

  jmethodID test_method = (env)->GetMethodID( klass, "get_property", "(Ljava/lang/String;)LTestObject;" );
  assert( test_method );

  jvalue args[1];
  args[0].l = env->NewStringUTF("k");

  jobject rv = env->CallObjectMethodA(obj, test_method, args );

  jthrowable exc = env->ExceptionOccurred();
  if(exc)
  {
    env->ExceptionDescribe();
    env->ExceptionClear();
  }

  //TODO: do something with rv
```

}

Comment: Oops. I missed copying in the implementation of the native function. Still the same error though.

Comment: Hmm? get_1property? I didn't used JNI at all, but why should an *interface* put something in the middle of a method name (as opposed to adding prefix or suffix), ever?

Comment: @whitequark - I think this is due to the underscore in the name. However its the output from `javah TestObject` which the recommeded way to generate those prototypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally the JVM expects to find native method definitions in a shared library that has been loaded via `System#load` or `System#loadLibrary`, and in most cases that is the most convenient approach. However, there does exist an alternative for situations like yours, where you would prefer to include the implementations directly in your executable.

If you call [`JNIEnv::RegisterNatives`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17734), you can instead pass the JVM a list of function pointers corresponding to the native methods in a particular class. When some Java code calls one of those methods, the JVM will know to invoke the function pointer you passed to `RegisterNatives` instead of searching through dynamically-loaded libraries.

```c
JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {
        "frobFabulously",
        "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V",
        reinterpret_cast<void*>(NativeFrobFabulouslyImpl)
    },
};

env->RegisterNatives(clazz, methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(JNINativeMethod));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've messed with JNI, so I'm a little rusty on the topic. I think your problem is that you're declaring the `get_property` method as `native`. This means that the JVM expects to find a shared library exposing the `get_property` method. Here's the documentation on [`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`](http://doc.java.sun.com/DocWeb/api/java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError).

> `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is thrown when (1) attempting to call a native
>   method that has not been loaded or (2) when loadLibrary or load method
>   in Runtime or System is called for a file that cannot be found.

You declare a Java method `native` only if you're going to implement that method in C or C++ and then call it from Java. Since you're trying to do the opposite, i.e call Java methods from native code, you need to actually implement the `get_property` method in Java. In native code you'll then create a class instance of `TestObject` and call the `get_property` method on this instance.

I found a [Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html#11202) on how to embed the JVM in native code. The [book](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html) itself begins with examples of how to call native code from Java.

Comment: Apologies. I am implementing the get_property function in C++. Somehow that fell out of my example. I'll ensure it gets put back in.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:
When you execute the Java application, add the missing link file with "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Something like

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[the link file path need be included] java xxx.class
```

The path can use absolute path. Hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try writing the JNI function in another file. When you javah TestObject.java, a file TestObject.h will be generated. Create a file TestObject.c with the implemented function. Then build a shared library using the native code.
( Something like g++ -G -I/pkgs/jdk1.4/include  TestObject.C -o libTestObject.so)
Also in TestObject.java, load the library statically like `static{ System.loadLibrary("TestIbject");`
The libTestObject.so should be added to LD_LIBRARY_PATH ( On a Linux environment)

Comment: I've tried this now, and it seems to work OK - but with some ugly limitations. If you're trying to share state between java and C++, you need to load the shared object first into the C++ application and then provide a way to expose state to it. i.e. to expose global a variable `char * foo` from the main app to be used in the  native function in java, you need to add a global `char ** foo_so` to the `.so` code, and provide a setter for that variable `void so_set_foo(char ** v)`, and finally register that from the main app using `so_set_foo(&foo)`. Ugly but maybe workable.